# Rest-spread not being transpiled when targeting edge with NextJS

Tags: ecmascript-6, babeljs, microsoft-edge, next.js

I am trying to transpile my ES6 code via Babel, I am using the `next/babel` preset along with `preset-env` and I'm using the `browsers: defaults` target.

The NextJS preset comes with `@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread` in its plugins array, I'm wondering why I am getting an error when testing on edge that says `Expected identifier, string or number`, and when looking in the compiled JS for the error, I see it happens when `{...t}` occurs.

Here is my `babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      'next/babel',
      {
        '@babel/preset-env': {
          targets: {
            browsers: 'defaults'
          },
          useBuiltIns: 'usage'
        }
      }
    ]
  ],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator',
    ['styled-components', { ssr: true, displayName: true, preprocess: false }],
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['.', './src']
      }
    ]
  ],
  env: {
    development: {
      compact: false
    }
  }
};
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end my problem was related to a package that was not being transpiled by babel. My solution was to use  NextJS' [next-transpile-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-transpile-modules) plugin to get babel to transpile the package code into something that would work on the browsers I need.

Here's an example of my NextJS webpack config with the package I need transpiled specified:

```
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules');

module.exports = withTM({
  transpileModules: ['swipe-listener']
});
```

Comment: How to transpile every module using `next-compose-plugins`?

Comment: You should not have to - it is the responsibility of the module itself to transpile its contents, and most modules do in fact do this, this was the first and only module I had to do this with. If you are looking into transpiling your own code - I would suggest looking into implementing babel in your project.

Comment: Thanks but some open source modules were not implemented to be transpiled but manual transpile worked, as in your answer.

Comment: In that case I don't know if there is an option with this next-transpile-loaders plugin to specify that all modules should be transpiled, sorry about that :/

Answer (score 0):

**SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number** error can occur in 2 situations.

(1) This error get trigger if you are using trailing comma after your last property in a JavaScript object.

Example:

```
var message = {
    title: 'Login Unsuccessful',
};
```

(2) This error get trigger if you are using a JavaScript reserved word as a property name.

Example:

```
var message = {
    class: 'error'
};
```

solution is to pass the class property value as a string. You will need to use bracket notation, however, to call the property in your script.

Reference:

[ERROR : SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number](http://mikemclin.net/fixing-error-script1028-expected-identifier-string-or-number/)

Comment: I have run ESLint on my project using the `no-trailing-comma` rule, and it reports no instances of trailing commas in my code, I also have the `no-reserved-keys` error enabled, so I am not allowed to use reserved keywords in my objects.

Also, this error is happening to me on Edge as opposed to earlier versions of IE, and the error specifically references a part of my compiled code with `{...t}` in it, so I think it is the spread syntax causing issues.

Comment: Can you try to remove that {...t} code from your compiled code and make a test with MS Edge to verify whether it caused the issue or not. it can help to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Hey - I figured this out in the end. It turned out to be a package that I had installed called `swipe-listener` that was not being transpiled by my babel config, and was using feautres not available on Edge.